# Does sound slow down in air or does it disperse?

Tags: acoustics

I know that tempature and humidity, etc. Affect how sound travels, but Google couldn't help so I came here.

Comment: Doesn't slow down, but disperses.

Comment: Why would you think it slows down?  Are you looking for an explanation for why sounds don't keep "going" forever?

Comment: @Jameslarge yes

Answer (score 1):

Air is the medium which allows sound to propagate. Sound only can propagate through air, water etc. In vacuum there is no sound. Sound waves' nature is similar to the ocean waves: no ocean, no waves. So, I think, you should think again about what you are actually asking about and repost the reformulated question.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment.